# Field with @Mock annotation initialize vs. @BeforeAll

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito, junit5

I have the following static mocking settings:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
TestClass{

@Mock
private static ClassB classBInstance;

    @BeforeAll
    static void setup(){
        MockedStatic<ClassA> mockedStatic = mockStatic(ClassA.class);
                mockedStatic.when(() -> ClassA.someMethod(ClassB.class)).thenReturn(classBInstance);
    }

    @Test
    void testMethod(){
        var mockedInstanceReference = ClassA.someMethod(ClassB.class);
    }

}
```

And here I am getting a null reference at *mockedInstanceReference*  field. But in this configuration:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
TestClass{
    @Mock
    private static ClassB classBInstance;

        @Test
        void testMethod(){
            MockedStatic<ClassA> mockedStatic = mockStatic(ClassA.class);
                    mockedStatic.when(() -> ClassA.someMethod(ClassB.class)).thenReturn(classBInstance);
            var mockedInstanceReference = ClassA.someMethod(ClassB.class);
        }

}
```

I have no problem, I am getting he proper mocked reference. My question is:. Why? What is the order between @BerforeAll annotation processing and @Mock field initialisation in junit 5?

Comment: `@BeforeAll` is only executed _once_ for your test _class_. `@Mock` fields are reassigned for every test _method_. `mockedInstanceReference` isn't a field, it's a local variable. IIRC `mockStatic` returns an AutoClosable and is only valid for the current thread.

Comment: I didn't really get the connection between your thoughts and my issue. Could you pls elaborate them in details?

Comment: You asked what the order between BeforeAll and Mock is and I told you. `@BeforeAll` runs once for the class, `@Mock` fields are reassigned for every test method.

Answer (score -3):

It is because you are using the wrong version of junit. Downgrade it to juit 4 and it will work.

Comment: This is not the answer.